# Proving by induction on an inequality and big-O notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

No idea where to go with this,

Got a piecewise function
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when } n = 1 \\
                     3 & \text{when } n = 2 \\
                     5 & \text{when } n = 3 \\
                     3\cdot f(n-1) + 2\cdot f(n-3) & \text{when } n \geq 4 .
\end{cases}
$$

and I have to show that the function has the property that $2^{n−1} \leq f(n) \leq 2^n$ for any $n$;
lastly translate into big-O notation. But I have no idea how to go about this.

I figure I have the base case $f(1) = 1$, which it does as denoted by the first line 1, $n = 1$.

Then the assumption/induction, I just have $3\cdot f(k+1-2)+2\cdot f(k+1-3)$ and therefore have $3 \cdot f(k-1) + 2\cdot f(k-2)$ as my induction.

Comment: I think you should have $3f(n-2)+2f(n-3)$ in your definition, otherwise I don't think that it's true.

Answer (score 1):

Proof under the correction that $f(n)=3f(n-2)+2f(n-3)$:

Base cases:

$2^0\le f(1)\le 2^1$

$2^1\le f(2)\le 2^2$

$2^2\le f(3)\le 2^3$

Induction step: For $n>3$, assume $2^{i-1}<f(i)<2^i$ for all $i<n$. In particular:

$2^{n-3}\le f(n-2)\le 2^{n-2}$ and

$2^{n-4}\le f(n-3)\le 2^{n-3}$

Multiply the first inequality with 3 and the second with 2

$3\cdot 2^{n-3}\le 3f(n-2)\le 3\cdot 2^{n-2}$ and

$2\cdot 2^{n-4}\le 2f(n-3)\le 2\cdot 2^{n-3}$

Adding the two inequalities gives:

$3\cdot 2^{n-3}+2\cdot 2^{n-4}\le 3f(n-2)+2f(n-3)\le 3\cdot 2^{n-2}+ 2\cdot 2^{n-3}$

But

$3\cdot 2^{n-3}+2\cdot 2^{n-4}=3\cdot 2^{n-3}+2^{n-3}=4\cdot 2^{n-3}=2^{n-1}$

$3f(n-2)+2f(n-3)=f(n)$ and

$3\cdot 2^{n-2}+2\cdot 2^{n-3}=3\cdot 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2}=4\cdot 2^{n-2}=2^{n}$

It follows that:

$2^{n-1}\le f(n)\le 2^n$ which was to be proved.

Comment: I'm very confused on your But step. can you go through those 3 lines with me

Comment: I am adding the terms of the inequality above "But", and I'm using $2^p 2^q=2^{p+q}$ and the recurrence.

Comment: that makes sense I understand the left and right of the inequality. but how is 3f(n-2) + 2f(n-3) = f(n)?  Because everytime i do it, i keep getting 5fn - 12

Comment: What is your definition for $f(n)$?

Comment: isn't my definition for f(n) the entire piecewise?

Comment: I would call it recurrence, not piecewise. And $f(1), f(2)$ and $f(3)$ are called initial conditions.

Comment: any idea how to translate the answr into big O notation?

Comment: You may write it $C_1\cdot 2^n\le f(n)\le C_2\cdot 2^n$, where $C_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $C_2=1$, and this means that $f(n)=\Theta(2^n)$ (and of course $f(n)=\mathop{O}(2^n)$ too).